# Convert a mbtiles tileset folder into a single .mbtiles SQLite file?

Tags: ogr2ogr, mapbox, vector-tiles, mbtiles, pbf

I have a root tileset folder structured with the standard tiling scheme [`/tileset/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.pbf`](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/).

When I try using [GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html), I think I miss something:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f MVT sqlite.mbtiles ./tileset
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `sqlite.mbtiles' with the following drivers.
```

Second try:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f MVT sqlite.mbtiles tileset/*/*/*.pbf -oo METADATA_FILE="./tileset/metadata.json"
Warning 1: Invalid value for 'bounds' metadata. Ignoring it and fall back to present tile extent
ERROR 1: Cannot find min and max tile numbers
ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'tileset/10/525/365.pbf'!
```

(note that this last file does actually exist on the disk).

How to properly convert a `tileset/` folder to a single [SQLite3](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)-flavoured [`*.mbtiles`](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.3/spec.md) file?

I'm working on a Ubuntu server 18.04 through SSH (no GUI).

Some more info:

```
$ cat tileset/metadata.json
{
  "name":"mytileset",
  "description":"",
  "version":2,
  "minzoom":0,
  "maxzoom":10,
  "center":"7.7459902,45.7073015,0",
  "bounds":"4.5954793,43.3513365,10.8965010,48.0632664",
  "type":"overlay",
  "format":"pbf",
  "json":"{ extra-large dataset }
}
```

I'm not able to figure out how to launch `ogrinfo` on the `tileset/` folder.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) from Mapbox, which allows you to either convert .mbtiles file to a folder or vice versa. There is also a [PyPi package](https://pypi.org/project/mbutil/), you can use.

This should work for you:

```
mb-util --image_format=pbf sqlite.mbtiles ./tileset
```